# How to convert a bag into multiple bags using apache pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file with two sets of  data like below:

```
1,abc,10,dss
2,efgh,as
1,abc,10,1234
2,efgh,as
1,abc,10,7899
2,efgh,as
```

records starting with #1 are one set and records starting with #2 are different set. So both have different structures. how to separate those two sets of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way ...

```
A = LOAD '/user/data/split.txt' as line:chararray;
B  = FOREACH A GENERATE  Flatten(TOKENIZE(line,' ')) ;
B1 = filter B by $0  matches '1.*';
B2 = filter B by $0  matches '2.*';
DUMP B1
DUMP B2
 or 
 SPLIT B INTO B1 IF ($0  matches '1.*'), B2 IF ($0  matches '2.*');
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the below error: 2016-12-16 10:32:17,936 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:
<line 3, column 46> Invalid field projection. Projected field [line] does not exist.
I ran the following code:grunt> file2 = LOAD '/hls/hls_wi/training/twofile.csv' USING PigStorage(',') ;
grunt> B  = FOREACH file2 GENERATE  Flatten(TOKENIZE(line,' ')) ;

Comment: you are using "USING PigStorage(',') ;" in place use "as line:chararray;"  and TOKENIZE and also confirm your input format .

Answer (score 0):

With new updated version of input, here is other solution

```
A = LOAD '/user/data/split.txt' as line:chararray;
B1 = filter A by $0  matches '1.*';
B2 = filter A by $0  matches '2.*';
or 
SPLIT A INTO B1 IF ($0  matches '1.*'), B2 IF ($0  matches '2.*');
```